# Is background thread only executed when the number of foreground threads executing is smaller than the number of processors?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, clr

According to learn.microsoft.com [[1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/1c9txz50(v%3Dvs.100)#multiprocessor-computers), [2](https://web.archive.org/web/20180405163558/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices#multiprocessor-computers), [3](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/1c9txz50(v%3Dvs.85)#multiprocessor-computers), [4](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/1c9txz50(v%3Dvs.71)#multiprocessor-computers)]:

> A background thread executes only when the number of foreground threads executing is smaller than the number of processors.

However, if I start 4 foreground threads on a 4-core CPU (without hyper-threading) and then start 4 background threads, the foreground threads and background threads will run side-by-side, which seems to contradict the statement above.

Code sample:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int numberOfProcessors = 4;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcessors; i++)
    {
        int threadNumber = i;

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Foreground thread {threadNumber} started.");

            for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++)
            {
                for (long k = 0; k < 10000000000; k++);

                Console.WriteLine($"Foreground thread {threadNumber} progress: {j}%.");
            }
        })
        .Start();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfProcessors; i++)
    {
        int threadNumber = i;

        var backgroundThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Background thread {threadNumber} started.");

            for (int j = 1; j <= 100; j++)
            {
                for (long k = 0; k < 10000000000; k++);

                Console.WriteLine($"Background thread {threadNumber} progress: {j}%.");
            }
        });
        backgroundThread.IsBackground = true;
        backgroundThread.Start();
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output:

```
Foreground thread 1 started.
Foreground thread 0 started.
Foreground thread 3 started.
Foreground thread 2 started.
Background thread 0 started.
Background thread 1 started.
Background thread 2 started.
Background thread 3 started.
Foreground thread 2 progress: 1%.
Foreground thread 0 progress: 1%.
Foreground thread 1 progress: 1%.
Foreground thread 3 progress: 1%.
Background thread 1 progress: 1%.
Background thread 0 progress: 1%.
Background thread 2 progress: 1%.
Background thread 3 progress: 1%.
Foreground thread 0 progress: 2%.
Foreground thread 2 progress: 2%.
Foreground thread 1 progress: 2%.
Foreground thread 3 progress: 2%.
Background thread 0 progress: 2%.
Background thread 1 progress: 2%.
Background thread 3 progress: 2%.
Background thread 2 progress: 2%.
Foreground thread 0 progress: 3%.
Foreground thread 2 progress: 3%.
Foreground thread 1 progress: 3%.
Foreground thread 3 progress: 3%.
Background thread 1 progress: 3%.
Background thread 0 progress: 3%.
Background thread 3 progress: 3%.
Background thread 2 progress: 3%.
...
```

Is the statement incorrect or do I simply get it wrong?

Comment: The MSDN docs are just blatantly wrong.  It does not give a definition of "foreground" vs "background" threads.  As far the OS is concerned, a foreground thread is one that has a window that the user is interacting with.  It does get a larger thread quantum.

Comment: Would this be a 4 core Intel with Hyperthreading? That would give you 8 threads on those 4 cores.  Maybe try that again with 8 instead of 4...

Comment: @Patrick Hughes, no hyper-threading, edited the question, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the statement is incorrect and in addition you are looking not at the lastest version of the documentation. If you lookup the **lastest version of the documentation** about [Managed Threading / Foreground and Background Threads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/foreground-and-background-threads) it states:

> **A managed thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread. Background threads are identical to foreground threads with one exception: a background thread does not keep the managed execution environment running.** Once all foreground threads have been stopped in a managed process (where the .exe file is a managed assembly), the system stops all background threads and shuts down.
>
> *Note*
>
> *When the runtime stops a background thread because the process is shutting down, no exception is thrown in the thread. However, when threads are stopped because the AppDomain.Unload method unloads the application domain, a ThreadAbortException is thrown in both foreground and background threads.*
>
> Use the Thread.IsBackground property to determine whether a thread is a background or a foreground thread, or to change its status. A thread can be changed to a background thread at any time by setting its IsBackground property to true.
>
> *Important*
>
> *The foreground or background status of a thread does not affect the outcome of an unhandled exception in the thread. In the .NET Framework version 2.0, an unhandled exception in either foreground or background threads results in termination of the application. See Exceptions in Managed Threads.*
>
> Threads that belong to the managed thread pool (that is, threads whose IsThreadPoolThread property is true) are background threads. All threads that enter the managed execution environment from unmanaged code are marked as background threads. All threads generated by creating and starting a new Thread object are by default foreground threads.
>
> If you use a thread to monitor an activity, such as a socket connection, set its IsBackground property to true so that the thread does not prevent your process from terminating.

The same goes for the documentation of the [Thread.IsBackground](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.isbackground?view=netframework-4.7.2) property:

> **Remarks**
>
> A thread is either a background thread or a foreground thread. **Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating.** Once all foreground threads belonging to a process have terminated, the common language runtime ends the process. Any remaining background threads are stopped and do not complete.
>
> By default, the following threads execute in the foreground (that is, their IsBackground property returns false):
>
> - The primary thread (or main application thread).
> - All threads created by calling a Thread class constructor.
>
> By default, the following threads execute in the background (that is, their IsBackground property returns true):
>
> - Thread pool threads, which are a pool of worker threads maintained by the runtime. You can configure the thread pool and schedule work on thread pool threads by using the ThreadPool class.
>
>   *Note*
>
>   *Task-based asynchronous operations automatically execute on thread pool threads.*
> - All threads that enter the managed execution environment from unmanaged code.

Comment: The docs are hardly old: the latest version of the documentation in English (15 Oct, 2018) refers to the article which contains the quoted fragment, [the version of documentation before that](https://web.archive.org/web/20180405163558/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices#multiprocessor-computers) (5 Apr, 2018) contains that exact quoted fragment, the most recent versions of documentation in Frech, German and Russian (30 Nov, 2017) all contain the quoted fragment.

Comment: @A.Milto: 3 of the links in the question you provided reference old versions of the framework (1.1, 3.0, 4.0). The link from your comment references a source from end of 2017 (via web.archive.org), the same [original link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/managed-threading-best-practices#multiprocessor-computers) is already updated.
Also take into consideration that the docs will not be updated on a daily basis - they just migrated them to learn.microsoft.com (which probably updated the timestamp).